# Shopify Backend app Session is not valid issue

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I'm new to shopify apps. I created app by shopify cli command. Now when I'm running the app and trying to hit an endpoint it's throwing bellow error.

[image]

can anyone please help me to understand what is going on. My ngrok is up and running and especially I'm just trying to run an endpoint from browser and the endpoint looks like this.

`http://localhost:51928/api/products/count`

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The big hint is in the error message. Your call is failing to provide the shop. So with no Shop, you have no auth. No auth, nothing works. Shopify ALWAYS sends the shop parameter. So whatever you are doing here, you're not, so you need to ensure you do.

Comment: Got the issue. But i've one doubt, I'm writing APIs locally, so how can I call those endpoints from postman locally.

Comment: Any local call, is local to a shop. So in your local calls, include the shop you're working on.

Comment: The shop parameter is in fact missing, but this doesn't seem to be the only issue. I'm receiving the same error with a shop param included and it's still showing "Session was not valid"

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question on another stack. But David is correct, Nick are missing a few parameters, [create-api-in-shopify-public-app-and-call-it-in-postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564592/create-api-in-shopify-public-app-and-call-it-in-postman).

Adding on, there is an Authorization header. The auth is a Bearer token with a timestamp, you'd need to generate a new bearer token fairly quickly before the auth is no longer valid